# Editor support for ndjson (aka JSON Lines, JSON Streaming)

Tags: text-editor, json

What interactive text editing / viewing apps have decent support for [ndjson](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec)?

It should at least treat each line as valid JSON, with the usual support for syntax checking / highlighting, folding, etc.

Without these, json logs are hard to parse at a glance, or require intermediate processing steps.

More advanced features are icing on the cake.

Any OS. GUI- or shell-based. Preferably open-source.

---

Related:

- [Log viewer with JSON support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37881/13548)

Answer (score 1):

I've added crude NDJSON browser to JSONedit 0.9.26 (Tools menu). It's basically list of JSON values where each value can be loaded separately to main editor window. I guess this would be preferable for "big" (bigger than screen) values, for "small" (i.e. few lines each) values using jq output might be preferable.

There are two features I've used previously to dig through multi-megabyte files - text filter, bookmarking and filtering by bookmark allowing gradually remove lines from view or include lines matching multiple text filters.
[image: JSONedit - NDJSON tool]